# Timeout handling in Simulink UDP Send/Receive

Tags: matlab, udp, simulink

I have a UDP Send/Receive block in a Simulink model that communicates with a remote machine. I defined a timeout value for UDP Receive block. The problem is when the response isn't received from the remote machine within the timeout period, the simulation stops. Instead, I'd like to use a dummy value if the remote machine times out (or not available) and the simulation to continue. Could someone guide me on how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: There are various implementations of the blocks. Which toolbox are the blocks from (e. g. "Embedded Coder", "Instrument Control Toolbox")?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the block provided by the "Instrument Control Toolbox", disable the "Enable blocking mode" (enabled by default) checkbox. I would suggest to use the block provided by the mentioned toolbox, if possible, since it is more suitable for the task you want to apply it for than the one provided by e. g. "Embedded Coder".